# tagName returning UPPERCASE name with namespace in IE 11 while IE 7 return lower case without namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11, xml-namespaces

I am trying to retrieve all the child elements in the Dom element with tag name into an array.

```
<xs:menu>
 <xs:submenu>
  </xs:submenu>
</xs:menu>

var item=menu.children.tags("XS:SUBMENU") ;

IE 7 has menu.children[0].tagname as  "submenu"
IE 11 has menu.children[0].tagName as  "XS:SUBMENU"
```

how can I make  menu.children[0].tagName return same tagname ?

Comment: Just add `.toUpperCase()`. As to getting the namespace, there may be nothing you can do other than add it in yourself.

Comment: its also returning "XS:"  extra ..

Comment: You mean prefix (not suffix) or more precisely the namespace.

Comment: Is this supposed to be HTML or XML? (It matters.)

Comment: @Grasshopper: Well that's your problem. There is no `submenu` element in HTML.

Comment: As fare as I know, IE 7 it will omit the namespace if you don't define it using a `xmlns:xs`  as attribute in a parent element. Anyway I suggest not to use custom namespaces anyway. What is the reason why you would like to use them?

Comment: I have some old code which checks for tagnames and manipulates the dom elements . Its breaksing when i run in IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the namespace, use the `localName` property instead of `tagName`. It should not include any namespace and I have noticed it is more consistently lowercase.

Comment: localName returns  lowercase but with namespace in this case "xs:submenu" in ie 11 and just "submenu" in ie 7

Comment: So IE11 doesn't implement DOM4 properly. I suggest you report this as a bug to IE developers.